# Spark plug fouling every ride

Tags: carburetor, husqvarna

I have a 2004 husqvarna cr125. Was wondering if anyone else was having the same issues with the spark plug fouling out often. Anytime I ride for over 40 minutes or so I’ll have to change the spark plug. I’ve cleaned the air filter, tried different spark plugs, and have been running the mixture I was told to. A friend of mine that used to race told me to check out my carburetor but I’m not sure how to tell if I need a new one or how to even go about getting a new one because there’s no model number. Please help me out if you can, thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Sounds like it is running too rich on fuel, and or the oil mix is too rich if a 2 stroke.

Comment: You mention trying different spark plugs - do you have the correct heat range?